# Creating Jquery custom plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Do I need to include any built-in plugin of jquery while creating custom plugin. I have tried this simple code and I started to learning it.. I have done this simple code but it isn't working..

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
  this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$("a").greenify();
```

Comment: where is that simple code..?

Comment: do i need to add built in plugin?

Comment: Well, you have not shown us how you tried to use it.   Follow this guide:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user3765130 This thing works: http://jsfiddle.net/kkLyV/

Comment: @user3765130 how did you invoke .css from a javascript object..?!? That function belongs to jquery right..? `$(this).css()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` needs to be a jQuery object, `$()`, for the jQuery method `.css()` to work. Use this:

```
$.fn.greenify = function () {
    $(this).css("color", "green");
};

$("a").greenify();
```

Solution in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2MKTX/